# C++ function template overload: empty braces vs explicit int

Tags: c++, c++20, function-templates-overloading

There is some very basic example of C++ function template overloading resolution below (minimized from actual code)

```
struct S {
    S() {}
    S(int) {}
};

template <typename T = S>
void foo(T x) { std::cout << "S" << std::endl; }

template <>
void foo<S>(S x) { std::cout << "S spc" << std::endl; }

int main() {
    foo({});
    foo(0);
}
```

Here we have two cases. In first case compiler shall default-initialize something (like S) in second case convert int to something (like S)

[Live example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jMjon6)

I believe in both cases specialization shall win overloading because specialization perfectly matches and is really more specialized then primary template by partial ordering [temp.deduct.partial]

But both clang 11 and gcc 10.2 in this example agrees that in second case primary template wins. Is this bug in both compilers or (probably) I don't understand something about C++ standard?

Comment: The compiler will use as few conversions as possible.  `foo<T>`, where `T=int`, is a perfect match for `0`, so that is what the compiler picks, rather than picking `foo<S>` and having to construct a temporary `S` object from `0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's only a single candidate that participates in overload resolution:

```cpp
template <typename T=S> void foo(T);
```

The selection of function template specializations happens afterwards. In this case, we have:

- `foo({})` can't deduce `T` (because `{}` has no type), so instead we fall back to using the default argument for `T`, which is `S`. That gives us a viable candidate to call - `foo<S>`.

  Once we decide to call `foo<S>`, we then consider specializations. There is one, so it is chosen. This prints `"S spc"`
- `foo(0)` *can* deduce `T`, `T` is `int`. That gives us a viable candidate to call - `foo<int>`. There is no specialization for this, this [misleadingly] prints `"S"` (even though there is no `S` involved here).

Default template arguments only come into play when the actual template parameter can either not be deduced or is not explicitly provided.

If you wanted even `foo(0)` to call `foo<S>`, you need to prevent deduction from succeeding in picking `int`. But at that point, why even have a template, just have a function that takes an `S`.